# Solaris Containers on Xen

Tags: solaris, xen

Setting aside the "why?" for a moment, would it be possible to install a Xen hypervisor and have a Solaris DomU with several Zones / Containers running?

Just one of those hypothetical questions that occurs at random times, not actually thinking of trying it out just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why not, as long as you can get Xen to host Solaris -- I use this exact setup with several different versions of VMware with no issues.

In my environment, I have Sol10 VM's with anywhere from 1 to 30 zones running on top of ESX, ESXi or Fusion.  The zones live on a secondary (or more) disks, either as virutalised disks or raw LUN's presented from a SAN, formed into a zpool.

Comment: wow - I was expecting answers starting with "maybe".  

My guess is that Xen should be able to host Solaris at least in HVM mode.  Given that Sun's been doing some work with the Xen hypervisor I'd not be surprised if Solaris can be paravirtualized.